# Распознавание лица андроид

Tags: android

В андроиде есть возможность разблокировать экран с помощью фронтальной камеры - он сравнивает изображение с нее с изображением, которое было задано раньше.

Есть ли возможность реализовать аналогичную функцию в своем проекте? Типа считывается изображение с фронталки, сравнивается с исходным, если похожи то выполняется какая-то функция.

Answer (score 0):

Пример распознавания лица в этом приложении:

https://github.com/rohanaggarwal7997/Face-Lock-For-Android

В этом приложении выбираются 2 фотографии и сравниваются  между собой.

Update: нашёл еще одну библиотеку с документацией

https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! А может еще подскажите что делать с этой библиотекой? Ибо подключение стандартным путем выбивает ошибку типа 'roapply() not found'

Comment: Обновил ответ выше